# How to use if/else condition in Sass/HTML?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have form that I would like the save button to be disabled with different color. It is disabled since I cannot click on it, but I would like the color to be changed as well until all fields are completed. 
Currently the color is blue, when it is disabled and enabled. But I would like it to change based on condition.

```
<div class="medium-6 columns" *ngIf="!isLoading else updateLoading">
          <button md-button class="saves" type="submit" (click)="onSave()" 
          [disabled]="!editCardForm.valid">Save</button>
</div>
```

```
.saves {
        height: 2.375rem;
        width: 5.375rem;
        border-radius: 1.1563rem;
        color: white;
        background-color: #00B8E6;
        margin-left: 0.2rem;
      }
```

Comment: this is for Sass/Angular

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: it doesn't work since the class "save" is blue and I would like change when its not clickable

Comment: You just need an higher rank CSS selector `button.saves:disabled { color: ... }`. It will override then `saves` color.

Comment: ok great thanks Ploppy

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with form validation if your fields are inside a form for example. Here is a quick demo of how that can be achieved.

```css
form:valid .button {
  background : green;
}
```

```html
        <form>
            <label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required/><br/>
            <label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/><br/>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login"/><br/>
        </form>
```

The button will only get green, if the inputs have text, as required.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the button.

```
button.saves:disabled { 
          background-color: green; 
}
```

Comment: Please close this question to prevent duplicated content on stack overflow.